# Keyboard missing in simulator iOS 8 Xcode 6.1

Tags: keyboard, uitextfield, xcode5.1, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I have migrated code from **Xcode 5.x to Xcode 6.1**. Everything is working fine except the missing keyboard. Whenever I try to **enter text in textfield keyboard goes missing** but text is entered.

Why is this happening? Any fix?

[image: Screenshot for question]

Answer (score 2):

In simulator menu, click **Hardware>Keyboard>Toggle software Keyboard** or simply press **Cmd+K**.